# Django CreateView - if field is empty, don't create an object and instead redirect to different view. How do I do this?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a media model and a product model. When a user creates a product they first upload a picture and then after this, they're forwarded to the product detail page where they can edit the products attributes. This works fine, however if the user doesn't upload a picture I'd like the program to skip creating a media object and just go straight to the product detail page.

I've tried returning a reverse() function from form_valid() but this doesn't work so I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is and how I can fix this?

My code currently:

```
class ProductMediaCreate(generic.CreateView):

    model = ProductMedia
    fields = ('media',)
    template_name = 'media/media_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product_obj = Product.objects.create()
        
        if not form.instance.media:
            return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={'pk': product_obj.pk})

        form.instance.product = product_obj
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.product.pk})
```

However this produces the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'get'` when I submit the form on the CreateView without a picture.

**EDIT:** not sure if this'll help, but following the traceback for the error states the source of the error to be within clickjacking.py on the line: `if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:` *(I'm not sure what this means though)*

Thanks in advance for any help!

*- GoingRoundInCircles*

Comment: Have you checked whether the execution is reaching the `form_valid(...)` method?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - yes I've checked using print() statements, and it gets to the return reverse() section of code, with the correct pk as well, but it doesn't return the url and instead comes up with the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: You can try `if not self.request.FILES` instead of `if not form.instance.media`.

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko - This is still resulting in the same error message unfortunately. The code does reach return reverse() with this method too but then I get the same error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

You can't directly use reverse() in form_valid as form_valid() is expecting a response so you have to use HttpResponseRedirect() around the reverse function.

i.e.

```
if not form.instance.media:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('product_detail', kwargs={'pk': product_obj.pk}))
```

To get HttpResponseRedirect you import it from django.http:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

Hope that helps someone in the future! :)